# Oracle SQL - For the same two column values how many different third column

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT *
  FROM Client cl, Contact c, Location l
 WHERE l.locID = c.locID 
   AND cl.clientID = l.clientID
```

I want to find for same (`locID` and `clientID`) how many **different** `c.contactID` are out there?

Comment: You need to use `count(distinct ...)`

Comment: After converting join style, you can use `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.contactID)
  FROM Location l
  JOIN Client cl 
    ON cl.clientID = l.clientID
  JOIN Contact c
    ON c.locID = l.locID`

Answer (score 1):

You can use GROUP BY and COUNT(DISTINCT)

```
SELECT 
  l locID,
  l.clientID,
  COUNT( DISTINCT c.contactID)
FROM Client cl
JOIN Location l
  ON cl.clientID = l.clientID
JOIN Contact c
  ON l.locID = c.locID 
GROUP BY
  l.locID,
  l.clientID;
```

As we are not using the client table we can remove it. The query might run faster. (The optimiser might detect that it is not used and not query it anyway)

```
SELECT 
  l locID,
  l.clientID,
  COUNT( DISTINCT c.contactID)
FROM 
Location l
JOIN Contact c
  ON l.locID = c.locID 
GROUP BY
  l.locID,
  l.clientID;
```

Following the further request in the comments for for number of duplicates of `[ loc id, client id, contact id ]` we simply need to add contactID to the group by and put **COUNT(*)** instead of **COUNT( DISTINCT c.contactID)**.
The query therefore becomes.

```
SELECT 
  l locID,
  l.clientID,
  c.contactID,
  COUNT( * )
FROM 
Location l
JOIN Contact c
  ON l.locID = c.locID 
GROUP BY
  l.locID,
  l.clientID,
  c.contactID;
```

Comment: It will throw `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined` because each join column is present in both tables

Comment: @kendle Thanks, Is there way to show as group for those DISTINCT values of contact ID for corresponding (loc ID + client ID ) ?

Comment: I'm not sure to have understood what you want. You could use `l.loc || '-' || l.clientID` in the SELECT and the GROUP BY if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Kendle [ loc id, client id, contact id ]
[ x1, y1, z1 ]
[ x1, y1, z1 ]
first I want to find if there are records like in above ( loc id and client id and contact id are same), if so I want to remove duplicates (only removing excess records, so only one x1,y1,z1 record will be used for the following second part query). after that
I want query result for all records GROUP BY loc id , client id and ORDER BY loc id , client id